# Bash permission denied error on trying to source ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash

I can't work out why I am getting this error

```
-bash: /dev/ttys000: Permission denied
```

when I try to source my `~/.bash_profile`?  Nothing has changed in my setup (OS X 10.10.1), except a recent installation of Csound.

Comment: Maybe can be useful to know what is inside your `~/.bash_profile`...  Here outside there are more users of Linux not Osx than you can imagine... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark:
there is a script or a command in your `~/.bash_profile` that try to write on `/dev/ttys000` that is closed to write for that process/user.

If you want to identify where it is generated the error, try to enable the debugging of the current shell:

```
set -x                    # To enable debugging
source ~/.bash_profile    # source the file
set +x                    # To disable debugging
```

If you find who/why and you cannot solve the problem post another question about it.

---

Example:
In the file `aaa.sh` there is:

```
date +"%H:%M:%S"
ls /ahksfjkasd
echo Hi!
```

The output of `set -x; source aaa.sh; set +x` is:

```
++ date +%H:%M:%S
17:54:09
++ ls --color=auto /ahksfjkasd
ls: cannot access /ahksfjkasd: No such file or directory
++ echo 'Hi!'
Hi!
```

The error is generated from the line before (`++ ls --color /ahksfjkasd`)

Comment: Hi, thanks I have identified the line in `~/.bash_profile` causing the problems - it was `export GPG_TTY="$(\`tty\`)"`, where `GPG_TTY` is an environment variable required for the curses pinentry program used by GnuPG - https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Common-Problems.html.

I don't understand their recommendation, they want the value of `\`tty\`` to be assigned to `GPG_TTY`, but this does not work.  Removing the backticks gives the correct value of `tty` to `GPG_TTY`.

Comment: Take out the extra `\`` from your expression. (too late ;) ). Using a=`\`mycommand\`` or a=`$(mycommand)` produce the same effect (execute the command `mycommand` and store its output in the variable `a`). It's probably a missprint.

Comment: I did, currently it is `GPG_TTY="$(tty)`".